# Have to output two sets of two strings, but when only one string is inserted to the first scanf, the output is messed up

Tags: c, string, scanf

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// FIXME include the string library

int main(void) {
   char userService1[50];
   char userService2[50];
   char userService3[50];
   char userService4[50];
   int price1;
   int price2;


   printf("Davy's auto shop services\nOil change -- $35\nTire rotation -- $19\nCar wash -- $7\nCar wax -- $12\n\n");
   printf("Select first service:\n");
   scanf("%s%s",&userService1,&userService2);
   printf("Select second service:\n\n");
   scanf("%s%s",&userService3,&userService4);
   printf("Davy's auto shop invoice\n\n");


   if(strcmp(userService1,"Oil") == 0 && strcmp(userService2,"change")==0){
    printf("Service 1: Oil change, $35\n"); 
    price1 = 35; 
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Tire") == 0 && strcmp(userService2,"rotation")==0){
    printf("Service 1: Tire rotation, $19\n"); 
    price1 = 19;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Car") == 0 && strcmp(userService2,"wash")==0){
    printf("Service 1: Car wash, $7\n");
    price1 = 7;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Car") == 0 && strcmp(userService2,"wax")==0){
    printf("Service 1: Car wax, $12\n");  
    price1 = 12;
   }

   else{
      printf("Service 1: No service\n");
      price1 = 0;
   }

   if(strcmp(userService3,"Oil") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"change")==0){
      printf("Service 2: Oil change, $35\n\n");
      price2 = 35;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService3,"Tire") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"rotation")==0){
      printf("Service 2: Tire rotation, $19\n\n");
      price2 = 19;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService3,"Car") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"wash")==0){
      printf("Service 2: Car wash, $7\n\n");
      price2 = 7;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService3,"Car") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"wax")==0){
      printf("Service 2: Car wax, $12\n\n");
      price2 = 12;
   }
   else{
      printf("Service 2: No service\n\n");
      price2 = 0;
   }

   int price = price1 + price2;
   printf("Total: $%d\n", price);
   return 0;
}
```

The code takes two inputs (selected services). If the first input is "-" and the second "Car wax", this is the current output:

```
Davy's auto shop services
Oil change -- $35
Tire rotation -- $19
Car wash -- $7
Car wax -- $12

Select first service:
Select second service:

Davy's auto shop invoice

Service 1: No service
Service 2: No service

Total: $0
```

However, this is the desired output:

```
Davy's auto shop services
Oil change -- $35
Tire rotation -- $19
Car wash -- $7
Car wax -- $12

Select first service:
Select second service:

Davy's auto shop invoice

Service 1: No service
Service 2: Car wax, $12

Total: $12
```

I assume it has to do with the fact that when the single hyphen is input into the first `scanf`, it's only one string and so messes up the next `scanf`, but I don't know how to go about fixing this problem.

Comment: Exchange `scanf("%s%s",...` for `fgets()` into a wide buffer and then parse the buffer into `userService1, userService2`.

Comment: Tip: Enable all warnings to save time.  I'd expect `scanf("%s%s",&userService1,&userService2);` to warn about mis-match pointers/specifiers.

Comment: Use strings and the scanf function this way: scanf("%s%s", userService1, userService2);
scanf("%s%s", userService3, userService4);

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by *chux* in the comments, it's better to use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead of `scanf()` if you don't know how many words will be on the standard input. Then, you can parse the output of `fgets()` by [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), which splits the retrieved line into separate words. In order to do so, please replace the following lines in your code:

```
printf("Select first service:\n");
scanf("%s%s",&userService1,&userService2);
printf("Select second service:\n\n");
scanf("%s%s",&userService3,&userService4);
```

by the following code (yes it's not nice, but I leave further improvements as an exercise to you):

```
char line[50];
char* token;

printf("Select first service:\n");
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    if (token){
        strcpy(userService1, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (token){
            strcpy(userService2, token);
        }
    }
}

printf("Select second service:\n\n");
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    if (token){
        strcpy(userService3, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (token){
            strcpy(userService4, token);
        }
    }
}
```

You also have to add the following include:

```
#include <string.h>
```

But you have another mistake in you code. Please replace the `||` to `&&` in the following lines:

```
if(strcmp(userService3,"Oil") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"change")==0){
else if(strcmp(userService3,"Tire") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"rotation")==0){
else if(strcmp(userService3,"Car") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"wash")==0){
else if(strcmp(userService3,"Car") == 0 || strcmp(userService4,"wax")==0){
```

Then you should get the expected output.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/siA0XE)

Note: The code above works for cases where you expect not more than two words per input. If you want to process more words, it makes sense to wrap the `strtok()` in a `while` loop as shown in [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: @Cheeseriot: Was my answer somewhat helpful for you?